# General question about Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

This might be a very very basic question but it would be kind if you could help me anyway:

Why is $-x^{2n}e^{-x^2/2}\Bigg|^{+\infty}_{-\infty}=0$

Is it because $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(-x^{2n}e^{-x^2/2})=\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}(-x^{2n}e^{-x^2/2})$ and therefore:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(-x^{2n}e^{-x^2/2})-\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}(-x^{2n}e^{-x^2/2})=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(-x^{2n}e^{-x^2/2})-\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(-x^{2n}e^{-x^2/2})=0?
$$

Comment: It's because $e^{x^2/2}$ increases faster than any polynomial so the ratio of any polynomial and this function tends to zero. You can prove this by induction and L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply L'Hopital's Rule $n$ times to see that $\frac {x^{n}} {e^{x}} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ for every positive integer $n$. Now just replace $x$ by $\frac {x^{2}} 2$ to see that $x^{2n}e^{-x^{2}/2} \to 0$ as $ x\to \pm \infty$.

Comment: I get that for $x\rightarrow \infty$ but how do you get that for $x\rightarrow -\infty$?

Comment: $(-x)^{2}=x^{2}$ so the result for $x \to \infty$ also gives the result for the result for $x \to -\infty$

Comment: That is why I applied L'Hopital's Rule and showed that $x^{2n}e^{-x^{2}/2}$ tends to $0$ as $x \to \infty$. After this don 't go back to the original question and start again. If you write the definition of limit you will see that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} x^{2n}e^{-x^{2}/2}$ is same as $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{2n}e^{-x^{2}/2}$ because this function is an even function. (Changing $x$ to $-x$ does not change this function).